# Learning c++, need help regarding memory allocation

Tags: c++, memory, heap-memory

```
    int main() {

    Person *pSamuel;
    pSamuel = new Person("samuel", 28, Person::Male);
    delete pSamuel;
    pSamuel = new Person("samuel", 28, Person::Male);

    return 0;
}
```

Hi everyone I have a quick question regarding "new" and "delete".

As you can see I set pSamuel to a new Person object, I then delete it, and then I set it to a new object, why does it point to the same address? I thought I freed the memory when I typed delete. Is this just because of the allocation algorithm is reusing the same memory for optimization? Or am I missing something about the actual delete function? Or am I missing something about create a new person object with the same data?

I appreciate any help. I just started learning c++ yesterday so go easy on me as I come from python...where I could careless about memory locations. :P

Comment: Things get really weird when told not to use the `new` in the first place.

Comment: Mind blown...... Can you explain further?

Comment: @SamuelBarthelemy See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new

Comment: Doesn't `&*` cancel itself out?

Comment: @Charles Yes, if you use it on a pointer. If you use it on a class, well, they both could be overloaded :)

Comment: You could improve this question by removing the unnecessary parts, that is, everything starting from `pSamuel->walk();` onwards. Those lines do nothing interesting as far as the question is concerned.

Comment: @FabioTurati I cleaned it up, sorry about that.

Comment: No problem, just keep it in mind for future questions. You might want to read about creating a [mcve]. If the code you post isn't minimal you could get some downvotes.